# Assigning namespace to element locally

Tags: xml, xsd

I've got an xml file. I cannot change the xml structure therefore I have to change the xsd file. Problem is about namespace

```
<po:purchaseOrder orderDate="2001-01-01" xmlns:po="http://objectshop.com/ns/po" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://objectshop.com/ns/po po.xsd ">
<shipTo country="USA">
    <name>Alice Smith</name>
    <street>123 Maple Street</street>
    <city>Cambridge</city>
    <state>MA</state>
    <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
</shipTo>
</po:purchaseOrder>
```

So normally i should put ns in every element. If i do that it's fine. The question how do i  design xsd file. Especially how do i assign namespace locally in xsd?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://objectshop.com/ns/po"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:po="http://objectshop.com/ns/po">

<complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="shipTo" type="po:Address" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ></element>
        <element name="billTo" type="po:Address" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></element>
        <element name="items" type="po:Items" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></element>
    </sequence>

    <attribute name="orderDate" type="date"></attribute>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

Comment: You have to define elements in your XSD before refering locally. I don't quite understand what you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted XSD is incomplete, so it is hard to say what is your setup. So I'll explain two different options, based on the XML. One should account for your specific case.

If I start from the XML and generate an XSD from it, this is what you would typically get:

**XSD1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:po="http://objectshop.com/ns/po" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://objectshop.com/ns/po" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="XSD2.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="purchaseOrder">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="shipTo" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="orderDate" type="xsd:date" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**XSD2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="shipTo">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="postalcode" type="xsd:unsignedShort" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

These two XSDs validate your posted XML. What they show is how you would reference content that is in no namespace - which is what I think your problem is all about.

However, it is also possible to have such XML described by one XSD file. The "tell-tale" is when only the document element is qualified (in your case `purchaseOrder`), while everything else is "unqualified". To achieve this by default, the schema needs to be set up using `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:po="http://objectshop.com/ns/po" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://objectshop.com/ns/po" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="purchaseOrder" type="po:PurchaseOrderType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="shipTo" type="po:Address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="orderDate" type="xsd:date" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="Address">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="postalcode" type="xsd:unsignedShort"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Alternatively, for each element/attribute you could override the schema level default setting by setting up the form attribute. An example is below (it is intended for illustration only, not meant to match your XML).

```
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" form="qualified"/>
<xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:string" use="required" form="qualified"/>
```

In this case, the XML should be:

```
<po:purchaseOrder orderDate="2001-01-01" xmlns:po="http://objectshop.com/ns/po" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://objectshop.com/ns/po po.xsd ">
    <shipTo po:country="USA">
        <po:name>Alice Smith</po:name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Cambridge</city>
        <state>MA</state>
        <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
    </shipTo>
</po:purchaseOrder>
```